# Copy Data from Multiple Sheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy data from cells F11:Z22 on multiple sheets and output the data onto one summary sheet.

Sample of Data to Copy
[image]

There is the possibility to have new sheets added. I would like to get data from those sheets as well.

I have Sheets "SummarySheet", "Import", "TemplateSheet" I do not want to copy data from. The other sheets I do.

The ideal output would be just all of the values listed out in the "Import" sheet.

Example of Result
[image]

I tried a few different macros. This one logically works the best. When I execute it, nothing happens.

```vb
Sub SummarizeSKUdata()
    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
    Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long
        
    'Notes: "Src" is short for Source, "Dst" is short for Destination
        
    'Set Referances up-front
    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
    lngDstLastRow = wksDst.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row '<-defined below
    lngLastCol = wksDst.UsedRange.Columns(wksDst.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column '<-defined below
        
    'set the initial destination range
    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)
        
    'Loop Through all sheets
    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        'Make Sure we skip the Summary Sheet
        If wksSrc.Name <> "SummarySheet" Then
            If wksSrc.Name <> "Import" Then
                If wksSrc.Name <> "TemplateSheet" Then
                    
                    'Identify the last row occupied on this sheet
                    lngSrcLastRow = wksDst.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
                        
                    'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
                    With wksSrc
                        Set rngSrc = Range("F11:Z22")
                        rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
                    End With
                        
                    'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
                    lngDstLastRow = wksDst.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
                    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)
                        
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next wksSrc   
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Shouldn't the line `lngSrcLastRow = wksDst.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row` refers to `wksSrc` instead of `wksDst`? Like `lngSrcLastRow = wksSrc.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row` 2) It seems to me that the line `Set rngSrc = Range("F11:Z22")` will act on the active sheet, not on the `wksSrc` (which is not activated previously in the code). It probably should be like: `Set rngSrc = wksSrc.Range("F11:Z22")`.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much for pointing those outs. With a little extra finagling I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with this code below.

```
Sub SummarizeSKUdata()
Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long
    
'Notes: "Src" is short for Source, "Dst" is short for Destination

'Set Referances up-front
Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")

wksDst.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

'set the initial destination range
Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 2, 1)

'Loop Through all sheets
For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

lngDstLastRow = wksDst.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row '<-defined below
lngLastCol = wksDst.UsedRange.Columns(wksSrc.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column '<-defined below

    'Make Sure we skip the Summary Sheet
    If wksSrc.Name <> "SummarySheet" Then
        If wksSrc.Name <> "Import" Then
            If wksSrc.Name <> "TemplateSheet" Then
            
                'Identify the last row occupied on this sheet
                lngSrcLastRow = wksDst.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
                
                'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
                With wksSrc
                    wksSrc.Range("F11:Z22").Copy
                    rngDst.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                End With
                
                'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
                lngDstLastRow = wksDst.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
                Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)
                
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next wksSrc
```

End Sub